# Serialize dynamic Dapper result to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, dynamic, servicestack, dapper

I'm trying to serialize a dynamic Dapper result to CSV using ServiceStack.Text, but I'm getting a collection of line breaks. According to ServiceStack.Text, it can handle both anonymous and `IDictionary<string, object>` types.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
        {
            var data = conn.Query("select * from data");
            var output = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(data);

            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

When I use the same type, it works.

```
        IEnumerable<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>
        {
            new
            {
                Name = "Nathan",
                Id = 1,
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(CsvSerializer.SerializeToString(list));
        Console.Read();
```

What am I missing about Dapper's return type?

I know I can solve this by projecting onto a model class, but the beauty of my approach lies in the use of dynamics. Do I have any options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dynamic Generic IDictionary's like what Dapper returns should now be supported [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/18cab8b39a76754d809d0e8cefd151fc9fba6bdf).

This change is available from v4.0.43+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Wow, how do I buy you a beer, @mythz?  Confirmed and it's working flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Dapper's `Query` method returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, which is basically: `IEnumerable<object>` - where each row happens to implement `IDictionary<string,object>`. I wonder whether SS is looking for the `T` is `IEnumerable<T>`: in which case, yeah, that won't work well. You could try:

```
var typed = data.Select(x => (IDictionary<string,object>)typed);
var output = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(typed);
```

This does the cast in the projection, so that if `SerializeToCsv` is a generic method, it'll know about the interface support.

Dapper does not return anonymous types.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I tried that as an inline projection to no avail.

Comment: Question what CsvSerializer am looking to do the same thing nick ?.